# function pointer instead of #define

Tags: c

Up to now I use `#define` to map functions.

Exemple: if I have 2 physical uarts, to map `SendDebugString` to the matching physical uart I use:

```
#define SendDebugString(s) Uart1_SendDebugString(s)   // map to uart 1
```

or

```
#define SendDebugString(s) Uart2_SendDebugString(s)   // map to uart 2
```

How can I do the same using function pointers instead of `#define`?

Comment: How are the functions declared?

Comment: How do you want to keep check for hich uart needs to be used here? Runtime or compile time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let say the function signature is `int sendString(char* s)`.
You can then write:

```c
// declare SendDebugString as a pointer to a function
// accepting a string as argument and returning an int
int (*SendDebugString)(char *s);

// assign a function to SendDebugString
SendDebugString = Uart1_SendDebugString;

// call the function
SendDebugString("hello world!");
```

Comment: If I write in a definition file uartPack.h :
int (*SendDebugString)(char *s);
If this file is called from other many files I have: 
Error[e27]: Entry "SendDebugString" in module ... redefined in module ....

Comment: @Mich you have to put `extern` in front of `int (*SendDebugString)(char *s);` in the `uartPack.h` file, and in the `uartPack.c` you put `int (*SendDebugString)(char *s);`  without the `extern` keyword.

Comment: @Mich If the function pointer is global, the same rules apply as for any other global variable (like an `int`): it must be defined in one source file, and declared in the header with `extern`.